# is $2^n = \Omega(2^{n + k})$ for some constant $k$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

From the definition of $\Omega$ notation, this would imply that $2^n \ge c  2^{n + k}$. Taking the $\log_2$ of both sides and simplifying, I see that $n \ge (n + k)\log_2(c)$. If I pick $c = 1, n_0 = 1,$ and $k$ to be some negative constant, then I can see this is true. I am wondering if this is a correct analysis, and that if I pick a positive $k$, then it is false. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note that $2^{n+k} = 2^n 2^k$, so a constant multiple of $2^n$ as you set things up.  When you took log's, you mistakenly imputed $\log c$ as a factor when it actually is a term to be summed.

Comment: Ok, so since the RHS is larger than the LHS by a constant factor of $2^k$, then if k is positive, the statement is false correct?  Likewise, if k is negative, then the RHS will always be some fraction smaller than the LHS, so the statement would then be true.  Let me know if this is the correct thinking for this type of problem.

Comment: The big-Omega notation lets you lump in the constant factor $2^k$, whether $k$ is positive or not.  Just write $2^{n+k} = c 2^n$ where $c = 2^k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formalizing the hints of the comments into a full answer:

If $2^n = \Omega(2^{n + k})$ then $2^{n + k}=O(2^n)$, meaning:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+k}}{2^n}=c
$$

For some finite or zero constant $c$.

$$
=\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^k=2^k=c.
$$

$c$ is a finite or zero constant for all finite $k$.